# Add default value for nested object and remove duplicates from nested array in JSON using jq

Tags: jq

I have the following JSON:

```json
{
  "foo1": "bar1",
  "foo2": "bar2",
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "c1",
      "version": "v1",
      "foo": "bar"
    },
    {
      "name": "c5"
    },
    {
      "name": "c2",
      "version": "v2",
      "fooArr": []
    },
    {
      "name": "c5"
    },
    {
      "name": "c3",
      "version": "v3"
    },
    {
      "name": "c4"
    }
  ],
  "foo3": "bar3",
  "foo4": "bar4"
}
```

I'm trying to convert it to below by adding default version to items and removing duplicates by name

```json
{
  "foo1": "bar1",
  "foo2": "bar2",
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "c1",
      "version": "v1",
      "foo": "bar"
    },
    {
      "name": "c5"
      "version": "NA"
    {
      "name": "c2",
      "version": "v2"
      "fooArr": []
    },
    {
      "name": "c3",
      "version": "v3"
    },
    {
      "name": "c4"
      "version": "NA"
    }
  ],
  "foo3": "bar3",
  "foo4": "bar4"
}
```

I'm able to add default version using `.items[] | if (.version) then . else . + {"version": "NA"} end`. But it is only returning items and removing other values.  Is this  possible using jq? [jq playground link](https://www.devtoolsdaily.com/jq_playground/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.items |= (group_by(.name) | map(first | { name, version: (.version // "NA") }))
```

1. [`group_by(.name)`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#group_by(path_expression)) to group each duplicate name
2. [`map()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#map(x),map_values(x)) over the result

   1. Take the [`first`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#first,last,nth(n)) object
   2. Re-create the object with a fallback for version: `(.version // "NA")`

```json
{
  "foo1": "bar1",
  "foo2": "bar2",
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "c1",
      "version": "v1"
    },
    {
      "name": "c2",
      "version": "v2"
    },
    {
      "name": "c3",
      "version": "v3"
    },
    {
      "name": "c4",
      "version": "NA"
    },
    {
      "name": "c5",
      "version": "NA"
    }
  ],
  "foo3": "bar3",
  "foo4": "bar4"
}
```

---

##### [Updated Playground](https://www.devtoolsdaily.com/jq_playground/?#%7B%22inputText%22%3A%22%7B%5Cn%20%20%5C%22foo1%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22bar1%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20%5C%22foo2%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22bar2%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20%5C%22items%5C%22%3A%20%5B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22name%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22c1%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22version%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22v1%5C%22%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22name%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22c5%5C%22%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22name%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22c2%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22version%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22v2%5C%22%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22name%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22c5%5C%22%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22name%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22c3%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22version%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22v3%5C%22%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22name%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22c4%5C%22%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%5D%2C%5Cn%20%20%5C%22foo3%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22bar3%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20%5C%22foo4%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22bar4%5C%22%5Cn%7D%22%2C%22filterExpr%22%3A%22.items%20%7C%3D%20(group_by(.name)%20%7C%20map(first%20%7C%20%7B%20name%2C%20version%3A%20(.version%20%2F%2F%20%5C%22NA%5C%22)%20%7D))%22%2C%22rawOutput%22%3Afalse%7D)

---

Based on OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75803544/add-default-value-for-nested-object-and-remove-duplicates-from-nested-array-in-j/75803607?noredirect=1#comment133716430_75803607), you could 'combine' the original object to keep every other value then `name` or `version` using [Addition (`+`)](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Addition:+):

```
.items |= (group_by(.name) | map(first | . + { name, version: (.version // "NA") }))
```

[Playground](https://www.devtoolsdaily.com/jq_playground/?#%7B%22inputText%22%3A%22%7B%5Cn%20%20%5C%22foo1%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22bar1%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20%5C%22foo2%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22bar2%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20%5C%22items%5C%22%3A%20%5B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22name%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22c1%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22version%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22v1%5C%22%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22name%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22c5%5C%22%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22name%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22c2%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22version%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22v2%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22something%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22foobar%5C%22%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22name%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22c5%5C%22%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22name%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22c3%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22version%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22v3%5C%22%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22name%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22c4%5C%22%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%5D%2C%5Cn%20%20%5C%22foo3%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22bar3%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20%5C%22foo4%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22bar4%5C%22%5Cn%7D%22%2C%22filterExpr%22%3A%22.items%20%7C%3D%20(group_by(.name)%20%7C%20map(first%20%7C%20.%20%2B%20%7B%20name%2C%20version%3A%20(.version%20%2F%2F%20%5C%22NA%5C%22)%20%7D))%22%2C%22rawOutput%22%3Afalse%7D)

Comment: thank you for the response. In step 2.2 when recreating the object, instead of hard coding to just name and version, is it possible to include all other key values?

{
      "name": "c1",
      "version": "v1",
      "foo": "bar",
     "fooArray": [] 
    }

Comment: What do you mean by 'all other key values' ?

Comment: updated original post with the example

Comment: Please see my edit (and playground) were we use `. + { name, version: ()}` to 'combine' the original object with the new one to keep the other values

Answer (score 2):

You could define a default object, then add the real items to it. Existing fields will overwrite the defaults:

```bash
jq --argjson def '{"version": "NA"}' '.items |= (unique_by(.name) | map($def + .))'
```

```json
{
  "foo1": "bar1",
  "foo2": "bar2",
  "items": [
    {
      "version": "v1",
      "name": "c1",
      "foo": "bar"
    },
    {
      "version": "v2",
      "name": "c2",
      "fooArr": []
    },
    {
      "version": "v3",
      "name": "c3"
    },
    {
      "version": "NA",
      "name": "c4"
    },
    {
      "version": "NA",
      "name": "c5"
    }
  ],
  "foo3": "bar3",
  "foo4": "bar4"
}
```